# How do I make sdiff ignore the * character?

Tags: regex, diff

Here's what I'm sure is an easy one, but I can't figure it out.

I have two files:

```
file1: You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike
file2: You are in a maze of twisty little* passages, all alike
```

I want to perform `sdiff` on these files, but I want to ignore the `*` character.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `-I` will ignore the whole line I think, not the character.  If you want to ignore the character you can:

```
sdiff <(cat file1 | tr -d '*') <(cat file2 | tr -d '*')
```

Reference from `man sdiff`:

```
-I RE  --ignore-matching-lines=RE
              Ignore changes whose lines all match RE.
```